# How to use min() and max() function in solr range query?

Tags: solr, solrj

I am using solr facet range query to get the `project_score` facet.  Currently I have fixed start,  end and gap values. However I want to use the minimum value of project_score as start and maximum value as end. Ascending and descending sort query and stat are the ways I found, but that requires 2 or more queries. Is there a way to accomplish this in a single query? Something like: `facet.project_score.start=min(project_score)`?

Comment: what about caching min and max?

Comment: @marius_neo: How can I do that ? Could you give an example ?

Comment: I am assuming that you run this query on the server side. So every now and then you get the min and max project score and you save them to a cache which is being refreshed every N minutes. Simple Cache Sample: [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained). Then, when building the facet query, you retrieve the min and the max project score from your local cache and use them in your query.

Comment: ok, got it. But then there has to be a separate query fired at least once to get the minimum and maximum value. I was looking for doing it in a single query.